Dynamic tree data structure and HTML Table
I am trying to write code using TypeScript and HTML to create a table to display my data. However, I encountered difficulty due to the complexity of managing the "rowspan". Here is my data:
data = [
    { d: 1, A: [{ a: 11, C: [{ c: 111 }, { c: 112 }] }, { a: 12, C: [] }] },
    { d: 2, A: [{ a: 21, C: [{ c: 211 }] }] }
]

enter image description here
what's makes it more difficult is the fact that i want it to be dynamic. this is an other data to check :
data = [
    { d: 1, A: [{ a: 11, C: [{ c: 111 }, { c: 222 }] }, { a: 22, C: [{ c: 333 }, { c: 444 }] }] },
    { d: 2, A: [{ a: 33, C: [{ c: 555 }] }] },
    { d: 3, A: [{ a: 44, C: [{ c: 666 }, { c: 777 }, { c: 888 }] }, { a: 55, C: [{ c: 999 }] }] }
]

i tried multiple code but nothing is working.

what did you try? can you share the code you tried that would just require a correction to make it working?

Where does the letter "b" come from in the image? It is nowhere in your data.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Absolutely what I wanted, thanks!

Here is a JavaScript function that can create a table from that hierarchical structure:


function createTable(hierarchy) {
    const table = document.createElement("table");
    table.insertRow(); // header row
    return hierarchy.reduce((table, obj) => {
        // Extract information from object
        let data, arr, colName;
        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            if (Array.isArray(val)) {
                arr = val;
            } else {
                colName = key;
                data = val;
            }
        }
        // Create a table from the object
        let nextTable;
        if (arr?.length) { // If there is nested information: recur
            nextTable = createTable(arr);
        } else {
            nextTable = document.createElement("table");
            nextTable.insertRow(); // heading
            nextTable.insertRow(); // data
        }
        nextTable.rows[0].insertCell(0).textContent = colName;
        const cell = nextTable.rows[1].insertCell(0);
        cell.textContent = data;
        if (nextTable.rows.length > 2) {
            cell.setAttribute("rowspan", nextTable.rows.length - 1);
        }
        // Merge nextTable into table:
        const tbody = table.children[0];
        while (nextTable.rows.length > 1) {
            tbody.appendChild(nextTable.rows[1]);
        }
        if (nextTable.rows[0].cells.length > table.rows[0].cells.length) {
            table.rows[0].remove();
            tbody.insertBefore(nextTable.rows[0], table.rows[0]);
        }
        return table;
    }, table);
}

// Demo with your example data:
const data = [
    { d: 1, A: [{ a: 11, C: [{ c: 111 }, { c: 112 }] }, { a: 12, C: [] }] },
    { d: 2, A: [{ a: 21, C: [{ c: 211 }] }] }
];
// Create the table HTML Element
const table = createTable(data);
// Add it to the current document:
document.querySelector("#container").appendChild(table);
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td, table { border: 1px solid; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; min-width: 50px; }
<div id="container"></div>



